# search multiple ora error messages using java regular expressions

Tags: java

I´m trying to figure out how to search multiple ora error messages using java regular expressions: ORA-6XXX , ORA-1578 , ORA-0060, ORA-01157 and ORA-27048

I have found for ORA-6XXX would be: ORA-6[0-9][0-9][0-9] but if I want to add/include the other ORA error #, Which regular expression will meet this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to find only ORA with particular numbers like `ORA-1578` or is `ORA-0001` is also acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

Try this expression

`ORA-\d+.` That will give you any number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try

```
ORA-[0-9]{4,5}$
```

Which is allow `ORA-XXXX` or `ORA-XXXXX`

Comment: @Pshemo Yep! no problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you need so

1. if you want to accept ORA with number containing 3, 4 or 5 digits then you can use `ORA-\\d{3,5}`
2. if you want to accept ORA with any 3 digits but for 4 digits only `1578` , `0060` and for 5 digits only `01157`, `27048` then try

   ```
   ORA-(\\d{3}|1578|0060|01157|27048)(?!\\d)
   ```

   This will accept `ORA` with any 3 digits OR 1578 OR 0060 OR 01157 OR 27048 after it. Additionally I make sure that there is no digit after this match.